# Requestmapping in spring with component-scan and autowire

Tags: spring

a strange problem is happening, when i use `<context:component-scan>` then my mappings works fine but `Could not autowire field:`, problem of auto wiring raised, but if i remove
`<context:component-scan>` then all auto wiring works fine but all mappings not working.

I don't understand what's wrong.

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.delance" />  
    <mvc:annotation-driven />           

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
           class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />            

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**spring.xml**

```
    <!-- DAO Implementations -->
<bean id="usersImp" class="org.delance.daoimplementation.UsersImp" />
<bean id="jobsDAOImp" class="org.delance.daoimplementation.JobsDAOImp" />

<!-- DAO -->
<bean id="jobsDAO" class="org.delance.dao.JobsDAO" />
<bean id="jobsService" class="org.delance.service.JobsService" />

<!-- Service Implementations -->
<bean id="jobsServiceImp" class="org.delance.serviceimp.JobsServiceImp" />
```

**JobsDAO**

```
public interface JobsDAO {
        public boolean addJobs(JobsBean jobs);
        public boolean deleteJobs();
        public List<JobsBean> findJobs(String query); 
}
```

**JobsServiceImp.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class JobsServiceImp implements JobsService {

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("jobsDAOImp")
    private JobsDAO jobsDAO;
```

**JobsController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class JobsController {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("jobsServiceImp")
        private JobsService jobsService;

        @RequestMapping(value="/AddJobs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addJobs(JobsBean jobsBean, ModelMap model) {              
                if(jobsService.addJobs(jobsBean)) {
                     return "SuccessJobs";
                } else {
                     return "ErrorJobs";
                }
        }
    @RequestMapping(value="/Create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String creatJobView(ModelMap model) {
            return "createJobs";
    }

    public JobsService getJobsService() {
        return jobsService;
    }

    public void setJobsService(JobsService jobsService) {
        this.jobsService = jobsService;
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
   SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.delance.service.JobsService org.delance.controllers.JobsController.jobsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delance.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=jobsServiceImp)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.delance.service.JobsService org.delance.controllers.JobsController.jobsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delance.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=jobsServiceImp)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delance.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=jobsServiceImp)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 28 more

Feb 19, 2014 12:10:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.delance.service.JobsService org.delance.controllers.JobsController.jobsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delance.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=jobsServiceImp)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.delance.service.JobsService org.delance.controllers.JobsController.jobsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delance.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=jobsServiceImp)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delance.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=jobsServiceImp)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: define mappings please

Comment: i have defined all my mappings, using annotation

Comment: your question is not clear. post xml context files or clarify what you are determining to be the problem

Comment: i have edited my post please have a look

Comment: very helpful edits. see my updated answer it has your solution.

Comment: Just a question. Why have you defined the `component scan` as well as defining the XML config? Also, you have the qualifier of `jobService` defined to the `Impl` class whereas you want to `autowire` it to an interface in your class. Why do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what each of

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.delance" />  
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

do.

The `component-scan` scans the specified packages and registers any bean definitions it finds, ie. classes annotated with `@Component` and its specializations (like `@Controller`).

The `annotation-driven` looks at all the beans in the `ApplicationContext`. If they are `@Controller` beans and have `@RequestMapping` methods, it registers special handlers for them with the `DispatcherServlet`.

In other words, you need both of those. The `component-scan` to generate beans and the `annotation-driven` to register them in the MVC stack.

If you are getting autowiring problems, your `ApplicationContext` is not setup correctly.

Comment: can you tell me, what is the problem in my ApplicationContext

Comment: @user3321738 Not without more details. It seems to me like you need to review your bean dependencies. A stack trace would be helpful too.

Comment: @user update your component-scan packages. In the servlet context, make it only scan packages containing `@Controller` classes. In you application context, make it scan everything but that.

Comment: @user But careful that component scanned beans don't overwrite XML beans.

Comment: it's not working, i have used everything, don't know what is the actual problem.

Comment: @user3321738 Please post your web.xml as well.

Answer (score 0):

`<context:component scan>` scans your config files for specific annotations (@Component, @Controller, @Service, and @Repository) and if it sees them, creates an instance of them in your context.

`<mvc:annotation-driven>` will scan for all other tags and perform whatever is associated with that annotation. So for `@RequestMapping`, it sees this and registers it as a handler for that url pattern.

You need both in your configuration. The reason you see the "Could not Autowire" error, is because your annotation driven context sees the `@Autowired` annotation, but does not have a candidate of the correct type to wire it.

Since you have

```
@Qualifier("jobsServiceImp")
private JobsService jobsService;
```

You need to create a JobService bean with id 'jobsServiceImp' so that it can be Autowired

```
<bean id="jobsServiceImp" class="my.package.JobService"/>
```

Alternatively, if you annotate your JobService class with an @Component("jobsServiceImp") annotation, your component scan will pick it up and create a bean automatically with the given qualifier.

If you still are receiving the autowire failed error, look at the stack trace. It is possible that it could not create an instance of JobServiceImp because it itself has @Autowired dependencies that there are no candidates for.

EDIT: After you posted your error it is clear.

> No qualifying bean of type [org.delance.dao.JobsDAO] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true),
>   @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=jobsDAOImp)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)

It says it can't create your JobsServiceImp because it needs a JobsDAO.

Make a JobsDAO bean to fill this dependency and you should be good to go

```
<bean id="jobsDAOImp" class="org.delance.dao.JobsDao"/>
```

Please note, if you have an @Qualifier ('name') attached to your @Autowired for the JobsDAO, you'll need to make sure the bean name matches that in order to get @Autowired in. I think I saw 'jobsDAOImp' from your stacktrace.

Comment: still not any luck, i have provided JobsServiceImp file, please have a look

Comment: There is new stack now, it says Could not autowire field: private org.delance.service.JobsService, in JobsController, but i have defined id for JobsService and it's implementation.

Comment: The reason is you put a qualifier on the Autowired JobService instance.  @Qualifier("jobsServiceImp") means you need to have a bean with id "jobsServiceImp" to autowire in. So you have 2 options: a) remove the `@Qualifier` (this will accept any JobService bean to be wired in) b) change `@Service` to `@Service("jobServiceImp")`. This will tell you component scan to create a bean with the id "jobServiceImp"

Answer (score 0):

Since you have

`<context:component-scan base-package="org.delance" />`

you don't need to create beans externally in xml file.

It is enough to keep @Service, @Controller, @Repository, @Component annotation on the top the classes for which you want to create beans. Spring container automatically creates beans for you. Since you have already kept those annotations

- Remove  definitions in your spring.xml
- Remove @Qualifier annotations in controller and Service

Try Running the application now